# Need Help in Importing data's from Excel in Android?

Tags: android, excel

I had used `JExcel` API for importing Data's from Excel,for using JExcel , I have written the following program:

```
public class ReadExcel {

    private String inputFile;

    public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void read() throws IOException  {
        File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
        File parent_dir = inputWorkbook.getParentFile();
        Workbook w;
        try {
            System.out.println("Parent dir"+parent_dir);
            if(parent_dir.exists() == true){
                System.out.println("Pardent_dir failed"+"1");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Pardent _ dir not failed"+"2");
            }
             if(inputWorkbook.exists()== true)
            {
                System.out.println("File Exists");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("File NOt Exists");
                System.out.println("Path "+inputWorkbook.getAbsoluteFile());
            }
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            // Get the first sheet
            Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
            // Loop over first 10 column and lines

            for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
                    Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
                    CellType type = cell.getType();
                    if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) {
                        System.out.println("I got a label "
                                + cell.getContents());
                    }

                    if (cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
                        System.out.println("I got a number "
                                + cell.getContents());
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ReadExcel test = new ReadExcel();
        test.setInputFile("c:/temp/Book2.xls");
        test.read();
    }

}
```

It works fine, but when i had used it in Android, I had got the following Exception

> 03-18 16:33:31.225:
>   INFO/System.out(8693): Parent
>   dirc:/temp 03-18 16:33:31.225:
>   INFO/System.out(8693): Pardent _ dir
>   not failed2 03-18 16:33:31.235:
>   INFO/System.out(8693): File NOt Exists
>   03-18 16:33:31.235:
>   INFO/System.out(8693): Path
>   /c:/temp/Book2.xls 03-18 16:33:31.245:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /c:/temp/Book2.xls 03-18 16:33:31.255:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):     at
>   org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:244)
>   03-18 16:33:31.255:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):     at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:77)
>   03-18 16:33:31.255:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):     at
>   jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:213)
>   03-18 16:33:31.255:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):     at
>   jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:198)
>   03-18 16:33:31.255:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):     at
>   com.san.test.MyActivity.read(MyActivity.java:93)
>   03-18 16:33:31.255:
>   WARN/System.err(8693):     at
>   com.san.test.MyActivity.displayAlert(MyActivity.java:62)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test.setInputFile("c:/temp/Book2.xls");
```

Android is a linux-based system, so there are no drives in there. Using "c:/" has no sence in android. Please, read the article about [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html). You can use [external storage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) to place your files and read from there.

Comment: Can't get your message,pls tell clearly, Then how i can do that

Comment: you can't use "c:" in android. There isn't one. Use /data/... and so on. Read this article to understand deeper : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Error log says that `FileNotFoundException`. So probably your path is missing here. You can push your excel file in the `/mnt/sdcard/` directory and then you can use like that:

```
test.setInputFile("/mnt/sdcard/Book2.xls");
```

Comment: don't use /mnt/sdcard/ instead you can use the getExternalDirectory() function to get the path.

Comment: @Reno: Yes I knew that, but this was already explained by **Vladimir Ivanov** that's why I had only given like that.

Answer (score 1):

I had fixed my issue, by placing the Book2.xls file in under raw folder and then read that file from that folder.

Thanks